# BB10 mailto scheme/mail client: percentage sign behaves strangely

Tags: email, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I have a WebWorks (PhoneGap) app that lets a user fill in a form and then opens the BB mail client (via a mailto URL) with the data from the form filled in as body. The form is written as a CSV line for easy import into Excel. Below is an example of what goes into the mail:

```
"test 1";"";"Customer";"AccMan";"Department";"";"n";"";"";"fee";"1000";"75%";"1000";"1000";"";"";"";"2015";"type";"";"Insurance";"Test 1";"NW";"";"";"";"";"";
```

All goes well on Android, iOS and almost well on BB, but: the form contains a field that is a percentage (the "75%"). When clicking on the mailto link, the two chars - the percentage sign and the following quote mark - are gone! This leaves me with a broken CSV line that doesn't import into Excel correctly.

I am sure I correctly URL-encode the line:

```
%22test%201%22%3B%22%22%3B%22Customer%22%3B%22AccMan%22%3B%22Department%22%3B%22%22%3B%22n%22%3B%22%22%3B%22%22%3B%22fee%22%3B%221000%22%3B%2275%25%22%3B%221000%22%3B%221000%22%3B%22%22%3B%22%22%3B%22%22%3B%222015%22%3B%22type%22%3B%22%22%3B%22Insurance%22%3B%22Test%201%22%3B%22NW%22%3B%22%22%3B%22%22%3B%22%22%3B%22%22%3B%22%22%3B
```

However, no matter what I try, the BB mail client omits the percentage sign (I am able to enter it manually afterwards).

Any ideas of the cause of this behaviour and how to fix this?

Comment: It seems BB double-URL-decodes the body. I.e. it tries to decode the `%"` string as if it were URL-encoded (while it's plain text). And because `"` is not a valid hex digit, it stops there and throws `%"` away as an invalid URL-encoded sequence. If I put `75%2525` into the encoded URL, it gets parsed correctly and shows 75% in the mail client. Doesn't seem like it should be so.

Comment: Tested this on a regular HTML page open in the BB browser, so actually has nothing to do with WebWorks.